# How to do many-to-many Django query to find book with 2 given authors?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have a query that requires to filter exactly 2 authors with the ID

Theoretically,

```
Book.objects.filter(author__id=1, author__id=2).
```

which is not possible.

How can I solve this problem?

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: Is Book to Author a Many2Many relashionship? Or it's just a Foreign Key?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Not intuitive at first but the answer is right in front of us.

```
Book.objects.filter(author__id=1).filter(author__id=2)
```

If you want an exact match, you could potentially further filter this result by those items that only have exactly 2 authors.

```
Book.objects.annotate(count=Count('author')).filter(author__id=1)\
                .filter(author__id=13).filter(count=2)
```

If you want exact matches dynamically, how about something like this?:

```
def get_exact_match(model_class, m2m_field, ids):
    query = model_class.objects.annotate(count=Count(m2m_field))\
                .filter(count=len(ids))
    for _id in ids:
        query = query.filter(**{m2m_field: _id})
    return query

matches = get_exact_match(MyModel, 'my_m2m_field', [1, 2, 3, 4])

# matches is still an unevaluated queryset, so you could run more filters
# without hitting the database.
```

Comment: hmmm, what if i have a list... how can I dynamically do it? i was using filters={} and Book.objects.filter(**filters)

Comment: [ignore the previous one] hmmm, what if i have a list of Author IDs... authors = [1,2,3,4] how can I dynamically do it? i was using filters={} and Book.objects.filter(**filters)

Comment: A dict can't have 2 keys of the same name, so that's not really possible without setting up a special way to handle your dict. Further complications when you have to determine which filters are chained separately and which are not.. If you're always looking for an exact match, you could pass in a list of items. Let me try writing an example.

Comment: thank you, it works. what's the difference between having a annotate and without?

Comment: If you don't annotate, the match is not exclusive. Book with authors [1, 2, 3] would match a search for a book with authors [1, 2]. If you'd like that, you can just remove the annotate and first filter.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita I tried this solution, but for me for _id in ids: query.filter(id=_id) return query, it returns an empty queryset. I've tried it several times and it's the same thing.

Comment: There is an error in the code - the query should be as follows:  `query = query.filter(**{m2m_field: _id})`

Comment: @rrauenzanice find. Updated!

Comment: Nested `filter()` adds multiple joins to the same table, I would rather use `query.filter(m2m_field__in=ids)`

Answer (score 1):

New questions are pointing to this one as a duplicate, so here is an updated answer (for one specific backend).

If the backend is Postgres, the SQL you want is (assuming the M2M table is called `bookauthor`):

```
SELECT *
FROM book
WHERE
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(bookauthor.author_id)
     FROM bookauthor
     WHERE bookauthor.book_id = book.id) = Array[1, 2];
```

You can get Django to generate nearly this SQL.

First, `pip install django-sql-utils`. Then create this `Array` class:

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Array(Func):
    function = 'ARRAY'
    template = '%(function)s[%(expressions)s]'
```

And now you can write your ORM queryset:

```
from sql_util.utils import SubqueryAggregate
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

books = Book.objects.annotate(
            author_ids=SubqueryAggregate('author__id', Aggregate=ArrayAgg)
        ).filter(author_ids=Array(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Postgres as a database, you could use `ArrayAgg` to collect author IDs in an array and then filter by that array:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

qs = (
    Book.objects
    .annotate(
        authors=ArrayAgg("author__id", distinct=True, ordering=("author__id",))
    )
    .filter(authors=[1, 2])
)
```

I've used `distinct` and `ordering` to make sure that IDs will have no duplicates and will always be in the same order.

This solution produces only one `JOIN` in the resulting SQL, whereas chaining several `.filter()` methods produces several `JOIN`s in the query.

Answer (score -3):

Q objects will help you. ***[Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)***

```
Book.objects.filter(Q(author__id=1) & Q(author__id=2))
```

Comment: @HID && @Yuji: what about ',' instead of '&'?

Comment: "That won't work" - "yep, you are right" :D facepalm

Answer (score -6):

You can use an "IN" query.
[Django Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#in)

`Book.objects.filter(author__id__in=[1,2])`

Comment: That would return a book that only has author 1 or author 2.