# How to get django model by ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I got a list of `Player` instances (a team) for example `team = [player1, player2, player3]`

How do I "get_or_create" the `Team` containing these and only these three players with one query?

These are my django models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Team(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
```

Comment: This answer should get you back on track

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301996/django-many-to-many-query

Comment: I'm working on an answer right now, but it might take a while for me to actually post it.

Comment: You know even if you only had to call `get_or_create` it would be 2 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says that `get_or_create` is a shortcut for:

```
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', birthday=date(1940, 10, 9))
    obj.save()
```

So I would adapt it to your use case as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count
import operator

players = [player1, player2, player3]

team = Team.objects
    .filter(reduce(
         operator.and_,
         [Q(players=player) for player in players]
    ))
    .annotate(count=Count('players'))
    .filter(count=len(players))

# Note that this ^ returns a QuerySet. With your posted model there
# might exist several teams with exactly the same players.  

if not team.exists():
    team = Team.objects.create()
    team.players.add(*players)
```

Slightly more complex but the workflow is the same:

- Query for existence.
- If not existent, create.

Comment: I accepted your answer, however I noticed a small mistake. `team.players.add()` doesn't accept an iterable, but multiple arguments, so it should be `team.players.add(*players)` using python's [unpacking feature](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). See it [in django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).