# Django AND query using Q objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given I have a `Product` model and a one-to-many `ProductTag` model.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    [...]


class ProductTag(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    tag_value = models.CharField()
    [...]
```

If I have 3 products with some tags:

1. **ProductA** [TagA]
2. **ProductB** [TagB]
3. **ProductC** [TagB/TagC]

**I want to dynamically query "products" with some tags.**

1. This query returns just "ProductA" (as expected).

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(producttag__tag_value="TagA"))
```

2. This query returns all 3 products (as expected).

```
Product.objects.filter(
    Q(producttag__tag_value="TagA") | Q(producttag__tag_value="TagB")
)
```

3. I would expect the following query to return just "ProductC"

```
Product.objects.filter(
    Q(producttag__tag_value="TagB") & Q(producttag__tag_value="TagC")
)
```

But I get an empty queryset. Why does query #3 not work?

Using `__in` query also returns wrong results (as expected)

```
Product.objects.filter(producttag__tag_value__in=["TagB", "TagC"])
```

The above query returns both ProductB / ProductC.

**UPDATE**

The reason why I am doing lookups with Q objects is that the query is based on user input from an API endpoint. e.g

- "tag=TagA"
- "tag=TagA AND tag=TagB"
- "tag=TagA AND NOT tag=TagC"

So I need to run a dynamic Django query based on the user input and not able to hardcode some query.

Comment: Query #3 effectively asks for the `ProductTag.tag_value` to equal both `TagB` and `TagC` at the same time on a single row, and that is obviously impossible. I get what you are trying to achieve, but still thinking on the possible solution. It's a consequence of the SQL model, you are always filtering based on a single row of a table...

Answer (score 0):

Query #3 effectively asks for the `ProductTag.tag_value` to equal both `TagB` and `TagC` at the same time on a **single row**, and that is obviously impossible. It's a consequence of the SQL query syntax/model, you are always filtering based on a single row of a table.

I didn't come up with anything fancier and more performant than chaining `EXISTS` clauses (only works on Django 3.x):

```
rel_tag = ProductTag.objects.filter(product=OuterRef('pk'))
Product.objects.filter(
    Exists(rel_tag.filter(tag_value="TagB")) & 
    Exists(rel_tag.filter(tag_value="TagC"))
)
```

Comment: BTW I tried using `EXISTS` (using Django 2.2x) 

```
tag_query = ProductTag.objects.filter(product=OuterRef('pk'))
qs = Product.objects.annotate(
    matched=Exists(tag_query.filter(tag_value="TagA"))
    & Exists(tag_query.filter(tag_value="TagB"))
).filter(matched=True)

```
Django raises `NotImplementedError: Use .bitand() and .bitor() for bitwise logical operations.`

Comment: Yeah, right, it was only fixed in the 3.x version. I'll amend a solution for older versions

Comment: TypeError: 'Exists' object is not iterable.

Comment: Well, then you are doomed) The only way to go is via annotate, but you'll have to give it names, and it complicates the dynamic query building

Answer (score 0):

The following query work:

```
qs1 = Product.objects.filter(Q(producttag__tag_value="TagB"))
qs2 = Product.objects.filter(Q(producttag__tag_value="TagC"))

queryset = qs1 & qs2
```

The above query returns just ProductC.

Roughly based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33271387/1682844

Comment: Wouldn't recommend using this, it's SQL `INTERSECTION` which is pretty poorly supported by Django (same for `UNION`), you may be unable to later make some of the modifications to the query. Please see my answer for the alternative

Comment: From the docs: In addition, only LIMIT, OFFSET, COUNT(*), ORDER BY, and specifying columns (i.e. slicing, count(), exists(), order_by(), and values()/values_list()) are allowed on the resulting QuerySet. Further, databases place restrictions on what operations are allowed in the combined queries. For example, most databases don’t allow LIMIT or OFFSET in the combined queries.

Comment: Updated my question with more details. Query is dynamic based on user input and will be difficult to use things like "Exists".

Comment: Well, nothing stops you from generating Exists / ~Exists queries the same way as you would generate `Q(producttag__tag_value="TagB") & Q(producttag__tag_value="TagC")` queries

Comment: Tell me if you need some guidance on how to achieve that