# How to perform AND condition on many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have two models

```
class Sale(AuthorTimeStampedModel):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product, related_name='sale_product', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}"
```

```
class Product(AuthorTimeStampedModel):
    id = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to apply query set to get all sales which have product_id 1 and 2

I am able to find Q function but it will result or condition but I want and condition

Comment: Try `Sale.objects.filter(product__id__contains=[1,2])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do many-to-many Django query to find book with 2 given authors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301996/how-to-do-many-to-many-django-query-to-find-book-with-2-given-authors)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sale.objects.filter(product__id__contains=[1,2])
```

Comment: this will return in OR condition not and condition